# spatie / laravel-sitemap | Adding new url replacing the previous file completely

Tags: laravel, xml-sitemap

I am using spatie/laravel-sitemap package to generate sitemap. I am able to generate sitemap nicely but when i try to add some new url it is replacing the previous urls completely. I am using the code below. Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

```
 $keywords = Keyword::all();
    $sitemap =  SitemapGenerator::create(config('app.url'))
    ->getSitemap();
    $location = Location::where('id', $location_id)->select('id', 'name', 'city_id')->with('city:id,name')->first();
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $url  = Url::create("/toptechnicians/{$keyword->keyword}/{$location->city->name}/{$location->name}");
        $url2 = Url::create("/topbusinesses/{$keyword->keyword}/{$location->city->name}/{$location->name}");
            $sitemap
            ->add($url
                    ->setLastModificationDate(Carbon::yesterday())
                    ->setChangeFrequency(Url::CHANGE_FREQUENCY_YEARLY)
                    ->setPriority(0.1))
            ->add($url2
                    ->setLastModificationDate(Carbon::yesterday())
                    ->setChangeFrequency(Url::CHANGE_FREQUENCY_YEARLY)
                    ->setPriority(0.1))
            ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
    }
```

Comment: I'm no expert in this package, but in general working with sitemap you create a new one here, and add your urls, where is all the other urls you are overwriting. Normally you delete your whole sitemap and create a whole new one from all the data is my experience.

Comment: Ya.It does work that way.